# CustomerAddRq QuickBooks XML including files in ClientsController CakePHP3

Tags: php, cakephp, integration, quickbooks

I'm working on integrating QuickBooks Desktop with a CakePHP 3.3 app using consolibyte's php dev kit (http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start / https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php). I was able to work through the quick start guide and add a customer from within my `QuickbooksController.php` (removed that test add and now receive 'No Data Exchange Required' when updating through web connector -which is good). but now i'm trying to move that queuing of adding a customer to where it should be, in `ClientsController.php`.  I'm encountering a couple different errors depending on what i `require_once`

**First Scenario:**
To start, I just tried to copy `QuickbooksController.php` so I `require_once`'d everything the same as in there.  This is why there are so many commented out lines.  This resulted in trying to load the file `/.php`.  `require_once(/var/www/html/pivot/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Driver/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [ROOT/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Loader.php, line 56]`

**Second Scenario**
I then figured I should only really need the Queue class, so that was the only class I `require_once`'d.  This resulted in the error `Class 'QuickBooks_Loader' not found`

**Third Scenario**
Next I included `QuickBooks_Loader` as well as Queue. This resulted in the error `Notice (8): Use of undefined constant QUICKBOOKS_BASEDIR - assumed 'QUICKBOOKS_BASEDIR' [ROOT/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Loader.php, line 56]
require_once(QUICKBOOKS_BASEDIR/QuickBooks/Driver/Factory.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory [ROOT/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Loader.php, line 56]
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'QUICKBOOKS_BASEDIR/QuickBooks/Driver/Factory.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/pivot/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Loader.php on line 56`

I can post my QuickbooksController.php if it would be useful, but for now omitting for space since I'm getting no errors when updating with Web Connector. Here is my [updated] Clients Controller
**ClientsController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'quickbooks-php-master' . DS . 'QuickBooks.php');

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\I18n\Time;
use Cake\Utility\Text;
use Cake\Mailer\MailerAwareTrait;
use Cake\Log\Log;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use QuickBooks;


/**
 * Clients Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\ClientsTable $Clients
 */
class ClientsController extends AppController
{
    use MailerAwareTrait;
    //...skipping to add function
  /**
 * Add method
 *
 * @return void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
 */
    public function add()
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout('dialog'); // we're gonna be opening in dialog
        $dsn = Configure::read('qbDsn');
        $client = $this->Clients->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $newClientData = $this->request->data(); // transfer post data to $newClientData so we can manipulate further
            //data manipulation omitted
            $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $newClientData);
            if ($this->Clients->save($client)) {
                // incorrect - need to use global namespace not App\Controller
                //$queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);

                // Updated - confirmed correct
                $queue = new \QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn)
                $queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $client->id);
                $this->Flash->success(__('The client has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $client->id]); 
            } else {
                Log::write('debug', $client->errors());
                $this->Flash->error(__('The client could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                //return $this->redirect(($this->referer()));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Complete QuickBooksController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'quickbooks-php-master' . DS . 'QuickBooks.php');
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'quickbooks-php-master' . DS . 'QuickBooks' . DS . 'Utilities.php');
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'quickbooks-php-master' . DS . 'QuickBooks' . DS . 'WebConnector' . DS . 'Server.php');
//require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'quickbooks-php-master' . DS . 'QuickBooks' . DS . 'WebConnector' . DS . 'Queue.php');
require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'quickbooks-php-master' . DS . 'QuickBooks' . DS . 'WebConnector' . DS . 'Handlers.php');
//require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'quickbooks-php-master' . DS . 'QuickBooks' . DS . 'WebConnector' . DS . 'Functions.php');

use QuickBooks;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Log\Log;
use QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server;
use QuickBooks_Utilities;
//use QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue;
use QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers;
//use QuickBooks_WebConnector_Functions;

//use QuickBooks_WebConnector_QWC;

/**
* Quickbooks Controller
*
* @property \App\Model\Table\QuickbooksTable $Quickbooks
*/
class QuickbooksController extends AppController
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->Auth->allow();
        $dsn = 'mysqli://qb@192.168.16.243/pivot';
        $qbwc_user = 'quickbooks';
        $qbwc_pass = 'password';
        if(!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn)) {
            QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
            QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $qbwc_user, $qbwc_pass);

        }
    }

    public function endpoint() 
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout('qb');
        $this->response->type(['xml' => 'text/xml']);
        $this->response->type('xml');
        $map = array(
            //QuickBooks_WebConnector_Functions::QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
        QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER => array(array($this, '_quickbooks_customer_add_request'), array($this, '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' )),
        //QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESRECEIPT => array( '_quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_request', '_quickbooks_salesreceipt_add_response'     ), 
            //'*' => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ), 
            // ... more action handlers here ...
            );
        // This is entirely optional, use it to trigger actions when an error is returned by QuickBooks
        $errmap = array(
            3070 => '_quickbooks_error_stringtoolong',              // Whenever a string is too long to fit in a field, call this function: _quickbooks_error_stringtolong()
                // 'CustomerAdd' => '_quickbooks_error_customeradd',    // Whenever an error occurs while trying to perform an 'AddCustomer' action, call this function: _quickbooks_error_customeradd()
                // '*' => '_quickbooks_error_catchall',                 // Using a key value of '*' will catch any errors which were not caught by another error handler
                // ... more error handlers here ...
                );

        // An array of callback hooks
        $hooks = array(
            // There are many hooks defined which allow you to run your own functions/methods when certain events happen within the framework
             QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => '_quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess',    // Run this function whenever a successful login occurs
            );

        // Logging level
        //$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL;
        //$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_VERBOSE;
        //$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEBUG;                
        $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP;        // Use this level until you're sure everything works!!!

        // What SOAP server you're using 
        //$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP;          // The PHP SOAP extension, see: www.php.net/soap
        $soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;        // A pure-PHP SOAP server (no PHP ext/soap extension required, also makes debugging easier)
        $soap_options = array(      // See http://www.php.net/soap
            );

        $handler_options = array(
            //'authenticate' => ' *** YOU DO NOT NEED TO PROVIDE THIS CONFIGURATION VARIABLE TO USE THE DEFAULT AUTHENTICATION METHOD FOR THE DRIVER YOU'RE USING (I.E.: MYSQL) *** '
            //'authenticate' => 'your_function_name_here', 
            //'authenticate' => array( 'YourClassName', 'YourStaticMethod' ),
            'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
            'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, 
            );      // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Server/Handlers.php file
        $driver_options = array(        // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Driver/<YOUR DRIVER HERE>.php file ( i.e. 'Mysql.php', etc. )
            //'max_log_history' => 1024,    // Limit the number of quickbooks_log entries to 1024
            //'max_queue_history' => 64,    // Limit the number of *successfully processed* quickbooks_queue entries to 64
            );
        $callback_options = array();

        $dsn = 'mysqli://qb@192.168.16.243/pivot';
        //$queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
        //$testKey = 25215;
        //$queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $testKey);

        $Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
        $response = $Server->handle(true, true);
    }

    function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
    {
        $this->loadModel('Clients');
        $client = $this->Clients->get($ID);

        // Create and return a qbXML request
        $qbxml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>' . $client->company_name . '</Name>
                        <CompanyName>' . $client->company_name . '</CompanyName>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>' . $client->address . '</Addr1>
                            <City>' . $client->city . '</City>
                            <State>' . $client->state . '</State>
                            <PostalCode>' . $client->zip . '</PostalCode>
                            <Country>' . $client->country . '</Country>
                        </BillAddress>';

        if (isset($client->mailing_address) && isset($client->mailing_city) && 
        isset($client->mailing_state) && isset($client->mailing_zip) &&
        isset($client->mailing_country)){
            $qbxml .= '<ShipAddress>
                    <Addr1>' . $client->mailing_address . '</Addr1>
                    <City>' . $client->mailing_city . '</City>
                    <State>' . $client->mailing_state . '</State>
                    <PostalCode>' . $client->mailing_zip . '</PostalCode>
                    <Country>' . $client->mailing_country . '</Country>
            </ShipAddress>';
        }
        if (isset($client->primary_phone)){
            $qbxml .= '<Phone>' . $client->primary_phone . '</Phone>';
        }
        if (isset($client->secondary_phone)){
            $qbxml .= '<AltPhone>' . $client->secondary_phone . '</AltPhone>';
        }
        if (isset($client->fax)){
            $qbxml .= '<Fax>' . $client->fax . '</Fax>';
        }        
        if (isset($client->email)){
            $qbxml .= '<Email>' . $client->email . '</Email>';
        }  
        $qbxml .= '</CustomerAdd></CustomerAddRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>';

        return $qbxml;
    }

    function _quickbooks_customer_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
    {   
        $this->loadModel('Clients');
        $client = $this->Clients->get($ID);
        $data = [
            'qb_list_id' => $idents['ListID']
        ];
        $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $data);
        if (!$this->Clients->save($client)){
            Log::write('debug', 'failed updating client qb_list_id in qb response');
            Log::write('debug', $client->errors());
        }
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
?>
```

**Namespace error after only `require_once`'ing QuickBooks.php as per Keith's suggestion (but not using global namespace)**

```
2016-11-02 09:50:16 Error: [Error] Class 'App\Controller\QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue' not found
Request URL: /clients/add.json
Referer URL: http://pivotstaging.efs.net/landings/admin
Client IP: 192.168.16.172
Stack Trace:
#0 [internal function]: App\Controller\ClientsController->add()
#1 /var/www/html/pivot/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(435): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/pivot/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(122): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
#3 /var/www/html/pivot/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(96): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\ClientsController))
#4 /var/www/html/pivot/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(60): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#5 /var/www/html/pivot/webroot/index.php(36): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#6 {main}
```

**Most recent error**

```
2016-11-03 07:47:39 Warning: Warning (2): require_once(/var/www/html/pivot/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Driver/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [/var/www/html/pivot/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Loader.php, line 56]
Request URL: /clients/add.json
Referer URL: http://pivotstaging.efs.net/landings/admin
Client IP: 192.168.16.172
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 146
require_once - ROOT/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Loader.php, line 56
QuickBooks_Loader::load() - ROOT/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Loader.php, line 56
QuickBooks_Loader::__autoload() - ROOT/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Loader.php, line 104
spl_autoload_call - [internal], line ??
class_exists - [internal], line ??
QuickBooks_Driver_Factory::create() - ROOT/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/Driver/Factory.php, line 95
QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue::__construct() - ROOT/vendor/quickbooks-php-master/QuickBooks/WebConnector/Queue.php, line 73
App\Controller\ClientsController::add() - APP/Controller/ClientsController.php, line 271
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/src/Controller/Controller.php, line 435
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 122
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php, line 96
Cake\Routing\Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 60
[main] - ROOT/webroot/index.php, line 36
```

Any nudges in the right direction would be most appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only thing you should be including:

> require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'quickbooks-php-master' . DS . 'QuickBooks.php');

In this code:

> $queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);

You have not defined the `$dsn` variable. Please define it.

**As far as the namespace issue goes...**

This is telling you that you're in a namespace:

> 2016-11-02 09:50:16 Error: [Error] Class 'App\Controller\QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue' not found

But that the class you're looking for isn't in the same namespace as you. The PHP lib you're using isn't namespaced, so you need it out of the global namespace (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php):

> $queue = new \QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);

Take note of the leading `\` which indicates the global namespace should be used when searching for the class.

Comment: Keith, thanks for the quick response.   When only including QuickBooks.php like you mention, I am receiving an error that it can't find the Queue class. After looking through QuickBooks.php more, it should be included from within there, correct? if `if (QUICKBOOKS_FRAMEWORKS & QUICKBOOKS_FRAMEWORK_QUEUE or 
 QUICKBOOKS_FRAMEWORKS & QUICKBOOKS_FRAMEWORK_WEBCONNECTOR)` is true. sorry - i forgot to add that $dsn in - its defined further up in the add function - `$dsn = Configure::read('qbDsn');`

Comment: Post your actual complete code then, so we can actually see what you're doing. Not going to be able to help if I can't tell what you're really doing here. Also, how about posting the actual error message, so I don't have to guess what the actual error is?

Comment: Updated question with more code & the entire (most recent) error. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the new code/error you've posted.

Comment: Doh. What a simple fix. Thank you.  This resolves the namespace error, however I'm now back into scenario #1 where the Loader is trying to require a file ".php"... I updated my code and posted the error.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you 100% POSITIVE that $dsn is defined and non-empty before you create the Queue object? $100 says it's an empty string.

Comment: Haha you were 100% correct.... Tested with hardcoded $dsn instead of reading from config and it worked. I should have known to double and triple check that after reading so many questions with that being your answer :D Thank you!!!!